# Preserve external changes in CouchDB with CouchRest Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, rest, couchdb

I'm using [`couchrest_model`](https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest_model) to manage some DBs in Rails. So far, it worked like a charm, but I noticed that if I `PUT` some data via HTTP request, CouchRest Model doesn't seem to realise that the changes are made, so it wipes off the whole record. Of course, I can see the changes in Futon, but not in Rails. When I enter the console, the previously saved instance is just not there.

Of course, I could use HTTP all the way, but I'd really like to make use of validations and other goodies that are available in `ActiveRecord` class.

Is there any chance that I can make these two guys work together?

---

P.S.

If you think/know that this approach will work with any other CouchDB Ruby/Rails gem, please, do tell! =)
I've mentioned CouchRest Model because IMO it's the most up-to-date and advanced gem out there.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that this one was so damn easy, it's just that I was using the wrong tool (apart from being a proper n00b). AFAICT, it's not possible to use `CouchRest Model` solely to carry out persistent operations on CouchDB backend. All external calls that alter the database record(s) in certain way will somehow "remove" that record from `ActiveARecord`. Instead, you'd probably like to use [`CouchPotato`](https://github.com/langalex/couch_potato), since it supports persistent operations.

I'll be glad to give checkmark if anyone comes up with vaguely better idea that this one.